# How can I connect to mongodb replica sets and authenticate by php script?

Tags: php, mongodb

I use following php script to connect to mongodb replica set:

```
$conn = new MongoClient("mongodb://mongodb1:27017,mongodb2:27017/?replicaSet=MyRepSet");

$db = $conn->test;
$collection = $db->items;

$item = array(
    'name' => 'milk',
    'quantity' => 10,
    'price' => 2.50,
    'note' => 'skimmed and extra tasty'
  );

  $collection->insert($item);

 $conn->close();
```

This works when I start mongodb without --auth and --key

However, when I start mongodb replica set with --auth and --key,  and create a user, like this:

```
> use test;
> db.addUser("test","123456")
```

When I try again with the above php script, I get this error:

```
Uncaught exception 'MongoCursorException' with message 'mongodb3:27017: not authorized for insert on test.items
```

How can I connect to mongodb replica set and authenticate by php script?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this

```
$connection = new Mongo("mongodb://test:123456@127.0.0.1:27017/mongodb1/?replicaSet=MyRepSet");
```

or if that doesn't work this try

```
$conn = new MongoClient("mongodb://test:123456@mongodb1:27017,mongodb2:27017/?replicaSet=MyRepSet");
```

Answer (score 0):

Base on your hint I try following:

on both mongodb1 and mongodb2:

```
use admin;
db.addUser("admin","123456");
```

Edit the php connection script:

```
$conn = new MongoClient("mongodb://admin:123456@mongodb1:27017,mongodb2:27017/?replicaSet=MyRepSet");
```

It worked !!!! Thanks a lots